# Unknown spatial reference in "Create Fishnet" files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, vector-grid

I am working on an unprojected dataset (lat/lon) on a WGS84 DATUM, and for that region I have used the "create fishnet" tool from "Data Management Tools" in ArcMap 10.2, in order to apply a grid over my region. Although, the coordinates I give as an origin of the fishnet are in lat/lon (in decimal degrees), the output of "create fishnet" is completely void of any spatial reference. When I import these shapefiles into a new project in ArcMap the message it appears is: "Unknown Spatial Reference: The following data sources you added are missing spatial reference information. This data can be drawn in ArcMap, but cannot be projected.". When I click "OK" the shapefile is imported and drawn correctly (correctly overlayed on a raster that is in lat/lon) but the outputs of "create fishnet" do not have any spatial reference. 
How could I give a spatial reference to these shapefiles (both lines and label points) that are produced by "create fishnet" tool. I need the spatial reference to be in Geographic Coordinate System and DATUM WGS84

Answer (score 3):

The first bullet in the Create Fishnet (Data Management) [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) states:

> The coordinate system of the output can be set either by entering a
>   feature class or layer in the Template Extent parameter or by setting
>   the Output Coordinate System environment variable.

You also have the option of [defining a coordinate reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000) on the data after it is created.

Answer (score 0):

To depict the process of fishnet is as below-

[image: fishnet]

**N.B.  Here i generated a fishnet has 10 rows and 10 columns( i omitted cell width and height by setting parameter to 0)**